# How do I reference a previously deployed schema within a new BizTalk project?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I have a BizTalk 2009 environment with a running application (call it A1) that contains a schema (S1). S1 has a few promoted properties defined in PropertySchema.xsd.
A1 is fairly simple, it has a Receive Port that polls a database for (debatched) S1 messages, and a Send Port that writes them to file.

I am now developing a new application (A2), and want it to contain an orchestration that has a direct subscription to the MessageBox to get some S1 messages with a certain promoted property value.

What is the correct approach to make the S1 schema, and its promoted properties, available for use within A2?

Should I:

- Add S1.xsd to the Visual Studio project for A2? (And what about PropertySchema.xsd?)
- Add Reference from the A2 project to the A1 assembly?

Or is there another way I haven't thought of?
Thanks.

Comment: I would probably stick S1 and its property schema in an assembly that both A1 and A2 can reference.

Comment: Thanks Derek. For now I have referenced the A1 assembly from A2. Since the A1 assembly is GAC'ed by the build, A2 picks up the DLL from there and the orchestration can see the promoted properties ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest create a Shared Application, which can contain all the Shared artificats.

References:
http://salmanzg.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/biztalk-shared-application/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577468%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. For now I'm able to fulfil my requirements using a Send Port (with appropriate filter) rather than an orchestration. I added a reference in the BizTalk Admin Console from A2 to A1 to make the promoted properties defined in A1 appear in the filter expression window. I will move the S1 schema into a separate shared application in due course as per the advice you link to.